# see connectionstring in text format

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

In visual studio I made my datasets and bindingsources and such using the toolbox, but how can I see my connectionstring now in code-format or can't I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside the `app.config` file that should have been added to your project.

Answer (score 1):

They should be visible in app.config file, take a look.